# SpringBoot: external application.properties not found in deploying war

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, application.properties

Am trying to configure properties in my Spring Boot application through external configuration by deploying war to tomcat container.

My `application.properties` file is kept at `tomcat_folder/conf/myappname/application.properties`

Am using this property file to load some aws configurations and db details like `spring.datasource.url` etc. and want to make these properties available to entire application and could be accessed like `@Value("${aws.access_key_id}")`

I have also changed the `Context.xml` file in tomcat `conf` by adding a parameter:

```
<Parameter name="spring.config.location" value="${catalina.base}/conf/myappname/application.properties" />
```

And my main application class looks like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);        
    }
}
```

After building and deploying war to `webapps` folder, when I start the server, I get the error

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Not sure what else to configure.

Answer (score 0):

I have test your configuration steps, looks fine for me.

You can use another way to test your config:

1. Put `application.properties` file into `tomcat_folder/lib/application.properties`
2. Remove below script in `Context.xml`.

`<Parameter name="spring.config.location"value="${catalina.base}/conf/myappname/application.properties" />`

3. Start the server.

Also, you can edit the `catalina.properties`

`shared.loader=${catalina.base}/conf/myappname/`

And kept your `application.properties` file  at

`tomcat_folder/conf/myappname/application.properties`

Comment: Putting properties under `lib` folder worked. Can you explain how?

Comment: Your config way is right, please double check if anything missing or any typo.

Comment: I had a `@PropertySource(value={classpath:application.properties}`. I guess this was the issue.